How can i resolve this issue on REnder
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.21.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.3 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.4 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.5 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11; 1.21.6 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.11
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg_resources==0.0.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pkg_resources==0.0.0

What I've Tried:

Upgrading pip with pip install --upgrade pip.
Upgrading setuptools with pip install --upgrade setuptools.
Attempted to create a virtual environment.

Any advice on how to resolve these errors would be greatly appreciated!
